# Is it possible to extract and/or pass along a query parameter in ESB REST proxy service

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am building a ReST to ReST proxy service. I need to be able to pass along some query parameters to that service that are incoming with the request. E.g.

myhost.zz/proxyService?foo=1&bar=2

When I define such proxy - and later try to extract the value of 'foo' I get null.
So is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You shouls define an API (if you really want a proxy service, look at the end of this answer) :

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="proxyService" context="/proxyService">
   <resource methods="POST GET OPTIONS DELETE PUT">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="foo" expression="get-property('query.param.foo')"></property>
            <property name="bar" expression="get-property('query.param.bar')"></property>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

call it with this url : http://host:port/proxyService?foo=12&bar=14

look at wso2-esb-service.log : INFO __SynapseService foo = 12, bar = 14

in the "resource", you can define a uri-template (URL Style = uri-template) with, for exemple, "/{scope}/*" and then when you call your api with http://host:port/proxyService/toto?foo=12&bar=14, you can access the "scope" with get-property('uri.var.scope')

to send a REST request, use a http endpoint with a uri-template using the same logic : `uri-template="http://other_host:port/Service/{uri.var.scope}/truc?abc={query.param.foo}&amp;dfc={query.param.bar}"`

**-->**
If you want to use a proxy service, you can access to query parameters like this :

request : http://esb:8280/services/MonService?param1=val1&param2=val2

```
<property name="PARAM1"
                   expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param1='),'&')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>

<property name="PARAM2"
                   expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param2='),'&')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use synapse xpath variable $url to read the query parameter values.
check this[1] for example.

1. [Reading Dynamic query parameter in WSO2 APIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824101/reading-dynamic-query-parameter-in-wso2-apim)